How to Fuse GPS as Odometry Source in robot_localization for Precise Localization Without Reliable IMU or Wheel Odometry?
I’m  using ROS2 Iron and the robot_localization package for sensor fusion. My system has a highly accurate GPS as the primary source for position, but I’m facing issues due to:
**1- Lack of reliable wheel odometry:**I currently calculate odometry data based on velocity and yaw rate, using both a simple and Ackermann model. The results are similar, but there is a significant drift when fusing odometry with the GPS and IMU. After running tests with different configurations (explained below), I believe the IMU, not the odometry primarily causes the drift. I attempted to mitigate this by setting high covariance values for the IMU’s pose estimation and lowering the covariance for its orientation (as the IMU is still somewhat useful for orientation).
Below is the code I used to set the IMU’s covariance in the fusion process:
imu0_config: [false, false, false, # Position X, Y, Z
              false, false, true,  # Orientation roll, pitch, yaw (using yaw only)
              false, false, false, # Velocity X dot, Y dot, Z dot
              false, false, true,  # Angular Velocity roll dot, pitch dot, yaw dot
              false, false, false] # Acceleration X double dot, Y double dot, Z double dot
imu0_pose_covariance: [9999.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                       0, 9999.0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                       0, 0, 9999.0, 0, 0, 0,
                       0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0, 0,
                       0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0,
                       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1]

2- IMU limitations: Our IMU is virtual and lacks a magnetometer, so it cannot reliably determine magnetic north. However, we use the COG (Course Over Ground) from the GPS to correct the orientation, and that part works well. The IMU drift still significantly affects the sensor fusion when fused with position data from GPS.
3- Goal: My goal is to use only the GPS as the primary source of position data for the sensor fusion process and eliminate the drift caused by the IMU and the calculated odometry. The GPS is extremely accurate, as shown in my tests. I would like to rely on it to generate accurate odometry data (X, Y) without using wheel odometry or IMU for position estimation.
Drift issue (Higher on high velocity regions)

Blue line (correct robot pose)
Green arrow (navsat fusion): Drift (incorrect pose)
Orientation is correct
What I've Tried:

GPS + IMU + Wheel Odometry (calculated): I calculate odometry analogous to the SINTAFE Master thesis and Autoware’s approach for integrating velocity and yaw rate to generate (X, Y) coordinates for odometry. However, the drift remains significant when this data is fused with the IMU and GPS.. check video

**GPS + IMU:**I attempted to ignore the first odometry source (odom0) by setting all odometry fields to false in the configuration and used only the odom1 = odometry/global, the GPS, and IMU. The drift persisted, indicating that the IMU (even with adjusted covariances) was the primary source of error. Check video

GPS only: Using just the GPS for position data gives accurate
results, but I need to generate local odometry (X, Y) from the GPS
coordinates (lat, lon) to feed into the EKF. As result the mapviz green arrow (which represents the navsat fusion) is fixed at the origin and just rotates around its axis (due to the imu), but does not track/follow the blue line (robot movement from the real_gps/fix topic). Check video


My Main Question:
Is it possible to configure the robot_localization package to use only the GPS as the main odometry source while ignoring the IMU and wheel odometry for position (X, Y)?
I would like to convert GPS coordinates (latitude, longitude) into local X, Y coordinates and feed that into the EKF as odom0 to be fused as odometry data. The GPS provides accurate position information, and I need a way to generate odometry data based solely on this reliable GPS.
As you can see in the previous videos (represented by the blue line from the /real_gps/fix topic), the GPS is very accurate. The green Mapviz arrow should follow this blue line, and I hope to achieve this by using GPS as the main odometry source.
Additional Details:

GPS Data: I can convert the GPS latitude/longitude into UTM
coordinates and then into local ROS coordinates.
IMU Problems: My IMU data is unreliable for accurate position as it is input in the odometry equation (x, y) = velocity * yaw) , though it works for orientation (yaw) correction using the COG from GPS.
Odometry Source: Since I don’t have physical odometry sensors, I aim to
generate odometry based solely on GPS data.

Current Configuration (partial example):
# real_bot_dual_ekf_navsat_params.yaml

ekf_filter_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: false
    frequency: 10.0
    two_d_mode: true
    publish_tf: true
    map_frame: map
    odom_frame: odom
    base_link_frame: base_footprint
    world_frame: map

    # Wished: Using odometry from GPS
    odom0: gps_odom  # (We do not have this currently. This is what we aim to achieve.)
    odom0_config: [true, true, false,
                   false, false, false,
                   false, false, false,
                   false, false, false,
                   false, false, false]
    odom0_queue_size: 10
    odom0_differential: false
    odom0_relative: false

I aim to replace the /odom with odometry derived from GPS data, which should work better for our purposes.
Any advice on how to configure this correctly or if there are better approaches to handle GPS-based odometry-only setup in robot_localization would be greatly appreciated!
Supporting Information
I am  sharing one of our frequently used configuration files and the script responsible for generating /odom, /imu, and /real_gps/fix. These files might help better understand our setup.
nmea_to_navsat_ackermann.py

#!/usr/bin/env python3
import rclpy from rclpy.node import Node from std_msgs.msg import
String from sensor_msgs.msg import NavSatFix, Imu from nav_msgs.msg
import Odometry from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist import pynmea2
import math import tf_transformations
class NMEAToNavSatFixNode(Node):
def init(self):
super().init('nmea_to_navsat_creating_odom_updated')
    # Variables for odometry
    self.x_ = 0.0
    self.y_ = 0.0
    self.yaw_imu = 0.0     # Integrated yaw from IMU
    self.last_cog = None   # COG from GPS in degrees

    self.wheelbase = 5.950  # Distance between axles in meters

    # Variables for speed and acceleration
    self.current_speed_kmh = 0.0
    self.current_speed = 0.0
    self.last_speed = 0.0
    self.last_time = self.get_clock().now()
    self.yaw_rate = 0.0

    # Initialize the buffer for the moving average filter
    self.filter_buffers = {
        'speed': [],
        'steering_angle': []
    }

    # Subscribers
    self.subscription_nmea = self.create_subscription(
        String,
        '/nmea_sentence_topic',
        self.nmea_listener_callback,
        10)

    self.subscription_imu_raw = self.create_subscription(
        Imu,
        '/imu_raw',
        self.imu_raw_callback,
        10)

    self.subscription_speed_steer = self.create_subscription(
        Twist,
        '/speed_steer_feedback',
        self.speed_steer_callback,
        10)

    # Publishers
    self.publisher_navsat = self.create_publisher(NavSatFix, '/real_gps/fix', 10)
    self.publisher_imu = self.create_publisher(Imu, '/imu', 10)  # Publishes the corrected IMU
    self.odom_pub = self.create_publisher(Odometry, '/odom', 10)

    # Variables to store the latest messages
    self.latest_imu_raw_msg = None
    self.latest_speed_steer_msg = None

    # Timer for logging
    self.create_timer(1.0, self.log_status)

def nmea_listener_callback(self, msg):
    try:
        if msg.data.startswith('$GPRMC'):
            nmea_obj = pynmea2.parse(msg.data)

            # Create NavSatFix message
            navsatfix_msg = NavSatFix()
            navsatfix_msg.header.stamp = self.get_clock().now().to_msg()
            navsatfix_msg.header.frame_id = 'base_footprint'
            navsatfix_msg.latitude = nmea_obj.latitude
            navsatfix_msg.longitude = nmea_obj.longitude
            navsatfix_msg.altitude = float('nan')  # Altitude as NaN

            # Adjust GPS covariance to reflect accuracy
            navsatfix_msg.position_covariance = [
                0.01, 0.0, 0.0,
                0.0, 0.01, 0.0,
                0.0, 0.0, 9999.0
            ]
            navsatfix_msg.position_covariance_type = NavSatFix.COVARIANCE_TYPE_DIAGONAL_KNOWN

            # Publish the NavSatFix message
            self.publisher_navsat.publish(navsatfix_msg)

            # Get COG and speed
            speed_knots = float(nmea_obj.spd_over_grnd)
            speed_kmh = speed_knots * 1.852  # Convert knots to km/h
            cog = float(nmea_obj.true_course)  # COG in degrees

            # Update COG if speed is above the threshold
            if speed_kmh > 2.5:
                # Normalize COG to [0, 360)
                cog_normalized = cog % 360

                # Update last_cog
                self.last_cog = cog_normalized

                # Convert COG to yaw in radians
                yaw_rad = self.cog_to_yaw(cog_normalized)
                self.yaw_imu = yaw_rad  # Update yaw_imu with GPS COG

    except pynmea2.ParseError as e:
        self.get_logger().error(f'Error parsing NMEA sentence: {msg.data}')
    except Exception as e:
        self.get_logger().error(f'Error processing NMEA: {e}')

def imu_raw_callback(self, imu_raw_msg):
    self.latest_imu_raw_msg = imu_raw_msg
    self.process_data()

def speed_steer_callback(self, speed_steer_msg):
    self.latest_speed_steer_msg = speed_steer_msg
    self.process_data()

def process_data(self):
    # Ensure that both messages have been received
    if self.latest_imu_raw_msg is None or self.latest_speed_steer_msg is None:
        return

    try:
        current_time = self.get_clock().now()

        # Update current speed
        self.current_speed_kmh = self.latest_speed_steer_msg.linear.x  # Speed in km/h
        self.current_speed = self.current_speed_kmh / 3.6  # Convert km/h to m/s

        # Steering angle in radians
        steering_angle_rad = self.latest_speed_steer_msg.angular.z  # Assuming it's in radians

        # Apply moving average filter on speed
        self.current_speed = self.apply_moving_average_filter(self.current_speed, 'speed')

        # Apply moving average filter on steering angle
        steering_angle_rad = self.apply_moving_average_filter(steering_angle_rad, 'steering_angle')

        # Calculate yaw rate based on Ackermann model
        if abs(steering_angle_rad) > 1e-6:
            turning_radius = self.wheelbase / math.tan(steering_angle_rad)
            self.yaw_rate = self.current_speed / turning_radius
        else:
            self.yaw_rate = 0.0

        # Calculate dt (time difference)
        dt = (current_time - self.last_time).nanoseconds * 1e-9
        if dt <= 0 or dt > 1:
            dt = 0.02  # Default value

        self.last_time = current_time

        # Integrate yaw rate to update yaw_imu
        self.yaw_imu += self.yaw_rate * dt
        self.yaw_imu = self.normalize_angle(self.yaw_imu)

        # Calculate linear acceleration
        if dt > 0:
            linear_acceleration = (self.current_speed - self.last_speed) / dt
        else:
            linear_acceleration = 0.0

        self.last_speed = self.current_speed

        # Update IMU (orientation)
        quaternion = tf_transformations.quaternion_from_euler(0, 0, self.yaw_imu)
        imu_msg = Imu()
        imu_msg.header.stamp = current_time.to_msg()
        imu_msg.header.frame_id = self.latest_imu_raw_msg.header.frame_id
        imu_msg.orientation.x = quaternion[0]
        imu_msg.orientation.y = quaternion[1]
        imu_msg.orientation.z = quaternion[2]
        imu_msg.orientation.w = quaternion[3]

        # Copy angular_velocity data
        imu_msg.angular_velocity = self.latest_imu_raw_msg.angular_velocity
        imu_msg.angular_velocity_covariance = self.latest_imu_raw_msg.angular_velocity_covariance

        # Set calculated linear acceleration
        imu_msg.linear_acceleration.x = linear_acceleration
        imu_msg.linear_acceleration.y = 0.0
        imu_msg.linear_acceleration.z = 0.0
        imu_msg.linear_acceleration_covariance = [
            9999.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 9999.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 0.0, 9999.0
        ]

        # Adjust IMU orientation covariance
        imu_msg.orientation_covariance = [
            0.1, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 0.1, 0.0,
            0.0, 0.0, 0.1
        ]

        # Publish the corrected IMU message
        self.publisher_imu.publish(imu_msg)

        # Calculate position change using yaw_imu
        x_dot = self.current_speed * math.cos(self.yaw_imu)
        y_dot = self.current_speed * math.sin(self.yaw_imu)

        self.x_ += x_dot * dt
        self.y_ += y_dot * dt

        # Create Odometry message
        odom_msg = Odometry()
        odom_msg.header.stamp = current_time.to_msg()
        odom_msg.header.frame_id = "odom"
        odom_msg.child_frame_id = "base_footprint"

        # Position and orientation
        odom_msg.pose.pose.position.x = self.x_
        odom_msg.pose.pose.position.y = self.y_
        odom_msg.pose.pose.position.z = 0.0  # 2D movement

        odom_msg.pose.pose.orientation = imu_msg.orientation

        # Linear and angular velocities
        odom_msg.twist.twist.linear.x = self.current_speed
        odom_msg.twist.twist.angular.z = self.yaw_rate

        # Set covariances to reduce reliance on odometry
        odom_msg.pose.covariance = [
            9999.0, 0,    0,    0, 0, 0,
            0,    9999.0, 0,    0, 0, 0,
            0,      0, 9999.0,  0, 0, 0,
            0,      0,    0, 9999.0, 0, 0,
            0,      0,    0,    0, 9999.0, 0,
            0,      0,    0,    0, 0, 9999.0
        ]

        odom_msg.twist.covariance = [
            9999.0, 0,    0,    0, 0, 0,
            0,    9999.0, 0,    0, 0, 0,
            0,      0, 9999.0,  0, 0, 0,
            0,      0,    0, 9999.0, 0, 0,
            0,      0,    0,    0, 9999.0, 0,
            0,      0,    0,    0, 0, 9999.0
        ]

        # Publish odometry
        self.odom_pub.publish(odom_msg)

    except Exception as e:
        self.get_logger().error(f'Error in process_data: {e}')

def apply_moving_average_filter(self, new_value, key, window_size=5):
    buffer = self.filter_buffers[key]
    buffer.append(new_value)
    if len(buffer) > window_size:
        buffer.pop(0)
    return sum(buffer) / len(buffer)

def cog_to_yaw(self, cog_deg):
    yaw_rad = math.radians(90 - cog_deg)
    yaw_rad = self.normalize_angle(yaw_rad)
    return yaw_rad

def normalize_angle(self, angle):
    return (angle + math.pi) % (2 * math.pi) - math.pi

def log_status(self):
    self.get_logger().info(f'Orientation (Yaw): {math.degrees(self.yaw_imu):.2f} degrees')
    self.get_logger().info(f'Speed: {self.current_speed_kmh:.2f} km/h')

def main(args=None):
rclpy.init(args=args)
node = NMEAToNavSatFixNode()
try:
rclpy.spin(node)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
pass
finally:
node.destroy_node()
rclpy.shutdown()
if name == 'main':
main()

I also tried implementing odometry based on velocity and yaw rate, inspired by:
SINTAFE Master Thesis: Link
Autoware: Link to gyro_odometer_core.cpp
However, I haven't achieved the expected results and would appreciate insights into using GPS as the main odometry source.
Configuration Files:
Below is one of our configuration files (dual_ekf_navsat_params.yaml):
# dual_ekf_navsat_params.yaml

ekf_filter_node_odom:
  ros__parameters:
    frequency: 20.0
    two_d_mode: true  # Recommended to use 2D mode for Nav2 in mostly planar environments
    publish_acceleration: true
    print_diagnostics: true
    debug: true
    reset_on_time_jump: true
    transform_timeout: 1.0
    sensor_timeout: 0.5
    use_sim_time: false

    map_frame: map
    odom_frame: odom
    base_link_frame: base_footprint
    world_frame: odom  # Use 'map' if you want the robot to move along the navsat arrow

    publish_tf: true

    odom0: /odom
    odom0_config: [true, true, false,  # Position X, Y, Z
                   false, false, true,  # Orientation roll, pitch, yaw (only yaw is used)
                   true, false, false,  # Velocity X dot, Y dot, Z dot
                   false, false, true,  # Angular Velocity roll dot, pitch dot, yaw dot
                   true, false, false]  # Acceleration X double dot, Y double dot, Z double dot
    odom0_differential: false
    odom0_nodelay: true
    odom0_relative: false
    odom0_queue_size: 10

    imu0: /imu
    imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                  false, false, true,
                  false, false, false,
                  false, false, true,
                  false, false, false]
    imu0_differential: false
    imu0_nodelay: true
    imu0_relative: false
    imu0_queue_size: 100
    imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

    use_control: false

    process_noise_covariance: [0.05, 0.0, ..., 9999.0]  # Adjusted as per requirements
    initial_estimate_covariance: [1e-9, 0.0, ..., 9999.0]

ekf_filter_node_map:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: false
    sensor_timeout: 0.5
    transform_time_offset: 0.0
    transform_timeout: 2.0
    frequency: 20.0
    two_d_mode: true
    publish_acceleration: true
    debug: true
    publish_tf: true
    reset_on_time_jump: true

    map_frame: map
    odom_frame: odom
    base_link_frame: base_footprint
    world_frame: map

    odom0: /odometry/global
    odom0_config: [true, true, false,
                   false, false, true,
                   true, false, false,
                   false, false, false,
                   true, false, false]
    odom0_queue_size: 10
    odom0_nodelay: true
    odom0_differential: false
    odom0_relative: false

    imu0: /imu
    imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                  false, false, true,
                  false, false, false,
                  false, false, true,
                  false, false, false]
    imu0_differential: false
    imu0_nodelay: true
    imu0_relative: false
    imu0_queue_size: 100
    imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

    odom1: /odometry/gps
    odom1_config: [true, true, false,
                   false, false, false,
                   false, false, false,
                   false, false, false,
                   false, false, false]
    odom1_queue_size: 100
    odom1_nodelay: true
    odom1_differential: false
    odom1_relative: false
    odom1_pose_rejection_threshold: 5.0
    odom1_twist_rejection_threshold: 1.0

    use_control: false

    process_noise_covariance: [0.05, 0.0, ..., 9999.0]
    initial_estimate_covariance: [1e-9, 0.0, ..., 9999.0]

navsat_transform:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: false
    frequency: 50.0
    delay: 3.0
    magnetic_declination_radians: -0.382271
    yaw_offset: 0.0
    zero_altitude: true
    broadcast_utm_transform: false
    publish_filtered_gps: true
    use_odometry_yaw: false

Question Recap:

Can I configure robot_localization to use only GPS as the odometry
source for position (X, Y) and ignore IMU and wheel odometry?
How can I convert GPS coordinates into odometry data to feed into the
EKF as odom0?

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on achieving accurate localization using GPS as the sole source of odometry in robot_localization.

What is the reason you are trying to use a robot_localization node? Does a Kalman filter with one input (& fixed covariance for that input) provide any benefit to the system?

This is a very long question that is going to take a very long time for anyone to digest and answer. I'll take a crack at some points, but you'd be far better off asking individual questions separately. That would also better serve the community, I think.
Anyway, a bunch of things, in no particular order:

You have a parameter called imu0_pose_covariance. That's not supported in robot_localization. You can't override sensor covariances. It will always use the values in the sensor messages.
I don't have the cycles to review your code or read a thesis, but it seems like you should be able to get by without having to transform the navsat data yourself.
Having just a GPS is not really a use case the package was intended to support.

However, I will call out issues I see with your config.
In your ekf_filter_node_odom:

Turn off debug mode. That is going to spit out a ton of data to a text file that won't help you, and it may affect the filter performance.
You are fusing absolute yaw from both your odom0 and imu0 sources. If those don't agree, the state estimate in the odom frame is going to rapidly jump back and forth between their values as the data arrives. If it wasn't an Ackermann model, I would recommend just fusing the velocities from your sensors for the that EKF instance. In this case, I would at least set yaw to false for imu0 and just use the yaw velocity.
You don't have your process noise covariance or initial estimate covariance specified in full. Any other values that you changed? With a huge process noise covariance in some dimension, you are basically telling the filter that its prediction is not to be trusted at all for that dimension, and all sensor data should be more or less trusted absolutely (assuming the sensor values have reasonable covariance values).

In your ekf_filter_node_map:

Turn off debug mode
For your odom0 source, you are fusing X, Y, yaw, X velocity, and X acceleration. I'm not clear on why you are fusing the X velocity and acceleration.
You are again fusing absolute yaw from two different sources (odom0 and imu0). This will cause the filter to jump back and forth between those sensor values as it receives the messages.

In your navsat_transform:

You say you are using the differentiated GPS values to generate a yaw that navsat_transform_node uses as its IMU heading, correct? Is that aligned such that 0 radians is east? If not, you need a value for yaw_offset.


How can I convert GPS coordinates into odometry data to feed into the EKF as odom0?

This is what navsat_transform_node does, and I see you have it in your config. I'm not clear on what you mean by this one.
What I always recommend is that you strip everything back and start slowly. First, focus only on your first odom frame EKF instance. Get everything in a state where your state estimate looks clean in that frame, even though it will drift from reality over time. It should be continuous.
Next, get the map frame EKF instance working without GPS data. I tend to fuse the same sources for that instance, with the same parameters.
Finally, add the GPS data. Really double-check that you have sensible values going into navsat_transform_node, and that the poses coming out of it are consistent with your world frame.
One thing to note is that if your map-frame state estimate does drift in its orientation, you might get into situations where the robot believes it is facing some direction Y, but the differentiated GPS data would suggest it is facing some other direction. In other words, as the GPS data arrives, it might start to look like it is moving sideways. It's why you should really have an earth-referenced heading going into the EKF as well.

Hello @automatom, thank you again for your detailed response and suggestions. I've implemented your recommendations: I turned off debug mode in both EKF configurations, ensured that yaw is only fused from one source in both ekf_filter_node_odom and ekf_filter_node_map, and adjusted the process_noise_covariance and initial_estimate_covariance matrices to reflect higher trust in the GPS and initial state, and relatively lower trust in the IMU and odometry, which are derived from GPS data using Ackermann and bicycle kinematic models from the literature. Setting the yaw_offset also helped.

I republish the sensor data (IMU and odometry) by generating new topics, adding covariance to them based on confidence levels. The odometry includes the truck's linear velocity in X, which I have reliable data for; hence, I set linear velocity X to true in the EKF configuration. Despite these adjustments, I'm still experiencing the persistent lateral drift. Both in ekf_filter_node_odom and ekf_filter_node_map, I've left only one source of yaw as you recommended.

Tomorrow, I'll be testing a new IMU that arrived (therefore I won't need to get yaw data from COG/ Nmea channel to get an estimation of Magnetic North anymore), which includes a magnetometer and claims to correct accumulated drift: https://gitee.com/HANDS-FREE/handsfree_ros_imu/. I'm hopeful that integrating this IMU improve the situation. If the issue persists, I plan to open a new, more focused question to address this specific problem and make it more helpful for other users. I also intend to edit and simplify this current post for clarity and utility. Thank you again for your assistance!

For reference, here are the links to my configuration files and scripts: Configuration file (dual_ekf_navsat_params.yaml): https://pastebin.com/VDgaq4Uq Script for generating and republishing sensor data (nmea_to_navsat.py): https://pastebin.com/Wj2Fhc0M These might help in diagnosing the issue. Thanks again for your valuable insights!  Result can be checked in this video: https://studio.youtube.com/video/yQiIHokQlDk/edit The orientation is stable, but drift is position too high. I suspect that is from odometry estimation. Do you suggest commenting out /odom as source and let just GPS and Imu?

. I wanted to clarify that until now, I didn't have a physical IMU. My yaw and yaw rate are calculated from GPS data within my nmea_to_navsat.py script (linked here: https://pastebin.com/Wj2Fhc0M). Both orientation and angular velocity are derived from GPS readings, not an actual IMU.I also use the Course Over Ground (C.O.G) from the Nmea channel to calculate the magnetic north (as we did not have a real imu then).

I also wanted to mention that I don't have wheel encoders on the truck due to its size. Therefore, I estimated odometry using methods similar to Autoware and the SINTEF autonomous truck project. Given the persistent drift I'm observing, could this estimated odometry be causing issues? Now that I have a physical IMU with a magnetometer, would relying solely on GPS and IMU data be sufficient for accurate localization using robot_localization, or do I still need an odometry source (/odom)?

For reference, here's my EKF configuration: https://pastebin.com/VDgaq4Uq. I've left odom0 blank in both EKF nodes since I'm unsure about using the estimated odometry. Any insights on whether my configuration should be adjusted, especially considering that my yaw is derived from GPS data and I now have a physical IMU with magnetomer data, would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Hi @automatom thanks for your assistance, it finally worked: https://youtu.be/3ITPx85csfY .  The sensor fusion worked when I bought an IMU, using COG it did not work. The configuration file I 've used was the same of the nav2 tutorial and it worked perfectly. I have understood the role of yaw_offset finally, which is fix the robot sliding behavior.
